# How should I keep my stores in react mobx for my Java entitiy models?

Tags: reactjs, store, mobx, mobx-react

I'm developing an application with React mobx. I have a complex data on the Java server side. How should I keep my data in my mobx store in for this data? I've read a lot about it. But I couldn't decide how to do it. 
I have lots of classes nested. I'm just writing a part. 
How should I keep nested classes? Or should I use inheritance in mobx? Thank you from now.
On the Java side I am holding List of PlanManagement.

```
public class Template {
private String templateName;
private String templateId;
.....
}

public class Group {
private String groupId;
private String groupName;
private String groupType;
private Template template;
.... 
}


public class PlanManagement {
private String id;
private String text;
private Group group;
.....
}

public class PlanCore extends PlanManagement {

private PlanStatusEnum statusValue;
private String statusType;
 ..............
}

public class OrderCore extends PlanManagement {

private OrderStatusEnum statusValue;
private String status;
private String task;
............
}
```

Comment: do you want to keep class instances in mobx store?

Comment: I did not understand what you said. Should I keep the same structure in Java on mobx? Example ; do not mind if I do Inheritance in mobx? Can you give me an example?@marzelin